# How can I run a command in windows that is triggered/detects logging in remotely vs local?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm running windows 2008 server.  I tried googling and looking on stackoverflow for doing this without adequate results.

I want to run a bit of automation on login/unlock of my windows box.  What the automation should do should be different based on whether I'm logging in/unlocking the computer locally vs remotely.  What the automation actually does is irrelevant to this question.

Some context:
If I login/unlock locally I want to start a program. If login remotely I want to kill that program (I already have scripts to do both).  I just don't know how to trigger each script based on the login type.

Is there a way to detect or trigger based on the type of login/unlock remote vs local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 tasks

- Administrative Tools
- Task Scheduler
- Action -> Create Task
- Triggers Tab
- New Button
- Begin Task -> On connection to user session
- Either: Connection from remote computer OR Connection from local computer